# How to import source directory as a database in enterprise architect?

Tags: database, enterprise-architect

I have a source directory of a java open-source software. I want to import that directory as database in Enterprise Architect. In that way class files are converted to tables while maintaining the associations. So that, I can apply different SQL quires to that database to extract code metrics and relationships among tables. I know, it can be done, because many previous students at my university has done that, however, those students aren't reachbale.

Comment: Can't be done. You need to import the code and run a transformation. Actually I'd do the latter manually.

Comment: Actually, it can be done, I have found the solution from a previous student and will share it after exploring.

Answer (score -1):

So, I have found the solution and its very simple. You can not create database of the source code from inside of Enterprise architect. However, you can import Enterprise Architect project file as an database source in SQL server. All the code files will be converted to tables while retaining the associations as Primary and Foreign keys. I have created a [short video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOJfuWNuJkQ) how to do that, also the following steps can be followed.

1. Import source directory as any of template (class diagram) in Enterprise Architect.
2. Open MS SQL server management studio and create a new (local) database.
3. Import the EA project file (.eapx) as data into that newly created database as
   Microsoft Access (Microsoft Jet Database Engine).
4. Set database destination as SQL Server Native Client 11.0.
5. Select desired tables when asked which tables to import, and finish.

Comment: You can simply use the built-in project transfer to convert an .eapx to an SQL server repository, but I fail to see how that is "importing a source directory as database"

Comment: @GeertBellekens, hi, I appreciate your suggestion. I posted the answer as its the only solution what I have found.  However, if you have better solution, then it would be more beneficial to post you solution (with all steps) as a separate answer.

Comment: I don't have another solution. I'm saying your "answer" is not a solution at all. It's simply a weird way to do a project transfer from .eapx to SQL Server.